# How to set og:image for a link that will be redirected to registration page url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, meta-tags

I have a link([www.example.com?token=sdsddsjfkbsdj](https://www.example.com?token=sdsddsjfkbsdj)) and want to share this link on social sites. When somebody clicks this link, my app redirects user to registration page. While sharing this link on social media, I want to display meta image as link preview. I have added `og:image` like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="'.$url.'" />
```

Because of redirection involved, this doesn't work and shows **Redirecting to** as preview.
This is preview on facebook.

[image]

Is there any workaround for this scenario ? Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this mean the `$url` needs registration to be viewed? How can facebook generate the preview if since it isn't going to register?

Comment: @apokryfos, `$url` is url of an image

Comment: Maybe you can have a link to a page that does a JavaScript redirect to `https://www.example.com/?token=sdsddsjfkbsdj` instead. Pages that do a 30X redirect don't have a body in the response so no `<meta>` tags will read